# Max and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table:

```
phone city country order_price customer_type_a customer_type_b
111   aaa  bbb     432         1               0
222   ddd  eee     900         1               0 
565   ggg  ttt     255         0               1 
678   kkk  ooo     654         0               1
457   aaa  bbb     100         1               0
364   aaa  bbb     150         0               1 
451   kkk  ooo     460         0               1
```

i want the result as following:
please note that the max(order price) is grouped by the customer type, A and B, so i want the max price for type a and type b customers

```
city country count(phone) count(customer_type_a) count(customer_type_b)  max_a  max_b
aaa  bbb     3            2                       1                      432           150
ddd  eee     1            1                       0                      900           0
ggg  ttt     1            0                       1                      0             255
kkk  ooo     2            0                       2                      0             654
```

i did this

```
SELECT 
 city,
 country,
 count(phone),
 count(customer_type_a ),
 count(customer_type_b ),
 (CASE WHEN customer_type_a = 1 THEN MAX(order_price)) MAX_A,
 (CASE WHEN customer_type_b = 1 THEN MAX(order_price)) MAX_B
FROM 
 table 
GROUP BY 
 city,
 country
```

i keep getting this error:
not a group by function, any help ?

Comment: Try `MAX(CASE WHEN customer_type_a = 1 THEN order_price end) MAX_A`

Comment: From the data you show, you better use sum(customer_type_a) instead of count(...), same for type_b

Comment: @gsalem i was mistaken, i meant it like you said using sum function not count, thanks for your detailed observation.

Answer (score 1):

*Conditional aggregation* is done the other way:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN customer_type_a = 1 THEN order_price END) MAX_A
```

Answer (score 1):

Your counts are incorrect.  They would be returning the same value, because `count(<whtever>)` simply counts non-`NULL` values.

I think you want:

```
SELECT city, country, COUNT(*),
       SUM(customer_type_a), SUM(customer_type_b),
       MAX(CASE WHEN customer_type_a = 1 THEN order_price END) as MAX_A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN customer_type_b = 1 THEN order_price END) as MAX_B
FROM table 
GROUP BY city, country;
```

You are getting an error in your query because `customer_type_a` and `customer_type_b` are not the arguments to an aggregation function and are not in the `GROUP BY` .